# Ubuntu detects that I don't have 6.6GB availabe to install

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, oracle

I'm using Oracle virtualbox in order to install Ubuntu. After I installed Oracle and opened the ISO file, Ubuntu detects that I don't have 6.6GB availabe to install. This is weird because I have hundred of free GB in my Hard disk, and I've also allocated 30GB to the virtual drive.

What can I do?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: When you created the VM, how much space did you allocate?

Comment: 30GB as I mentioned in my question (if I understand what you've asked)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Sure. How can I attach a file?

Comment: As it stands right now, you can't directly add an image.  Upload it to [imgur](http://imgur.com/), add the link, and I'll add it for you.

Comment: Do you have an idea what to do?

Comment: Try removing the VM, and re-create it.  See if that changes anything.  Let me know.